# How to generate a .pot file for better maintainability?

Tags: php, gettext

I have an application in which I used gettext to allow easy translation.

The problem that I have is that everytime I need to release a new version, I have to scan the .php files with the ICanLocalize scanner and this gives me a new .po file.

While it's ok for the default language, whenever I need to translate it to another one, I have to start all over again from that same new file.

I know I'm missing a big feature of gettext by doing this, but I don't know which is it or how to use it. I've tried googling and the only clue I got is that I need to generate .pot files instead of .po, but I really don't understand how they work.

My program adds new strings on every release, but also eliminates others, so I wouldn't like to leave those in the .po files.

I'm a little lost here, could someone give me at least a pointer in the right direction?

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**
I found that I can generate the file from within poedit itself, but it brings another problem. I have 3 different text domains on the app and want only one to be on the pot file... I'll keep looing for solutions

Comment: How do you create the pot file from poedit? I can't find the option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xgettext`is used to extract I18N'd strings from source. `msgmerge` merges an existing .po file into a new .pot file, and results in a new .po file. You'll have to handle the separate domains yourself, by only passing the appropriate source files.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio. I've been reading about this last night and found that I need to install Cygwin to run that commands, right? I thought I could do this from inside poedit but guess I'm going back to the good ol'text line!